# IOC container as mapping resolver

Tags: c#, unity-container, ioc-container

I want to use an IOC container preferably unity as a resolver function lookup

This what I have

```
 class ParmaterType {}

 class Monkey : ParmaterType {}
 class Handler {virtual void HandleMessage(){}}
 class MonkeyHandler : Handler {}

 class Main
 {
    Dictionary<Type, Type> _Mapper= new> Dictionary<Type, Type >()
    {  { typeof(Monkey) , typeof(MonkeyHandler) } }; 

   public void OnMessage(ParmaterType  type)
    {  
       Handler instance = (Handler)Activator.CreateInstance(_Mapper[type]); 
       instance.HandleMessage(type); 
     } 
 }
```

and what i want is something like this :

```
 IocContainer.Register(typeof(Monkey), typeof(MonkeyHandler ))

 public void OnMessage(ParmaterType  type)
 {  
     ((Handler) (IocContainer.Resolve(type)).HandleMessage(type);
 }
```

Comment: You need a handler interface, could be a generic one and registe handlers for their respective handler types. Then, based on message type, you need to ask the container for a registered handler type that corresponds to the message type (thus a generic handler type makes it much easier). But I am with @stuartd, the container is too generic for such responsibility, a suited handler factory would be better here.

Comment: The message handlers are split up in different places and are constantly added, I don't want to use the dictionary because than every new handlers I add i will have to go to the dictionary and add them , and they they are already registered in the IOC container . so it seems a but redundant

Comment: What mechanism are you using to dynamically register new handlers with your IOC container? I'd think you should be able to tie into that, but it's hard to say how without knowing more details.

Comment: Stay away from Unity, its terrible.

Comment: @Phill: at least share some facts rather than an opinion.

Comment: I do agree that Unity is terrible. Stay away from it. I've used several containers in different projects (including my own). The problem with unity is that it will try to resolve everything, no matter if the type is registered in it or not. It's horrible to debug.

Comment: @jgauffin: that's why you should resolve abstractions rather than implementations. You sound luke you blame container for a faulty oo design.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Name any other container that have the same behavior. None. There is a reason for it.

Comment: @jgauffin: SimpleInjector, Structure Map. Are two enough? If you believe there is a reason, name it, no one can't comment your opinion that is not supported by facts.

Comment: The problem is that you get undefined behavior. For all registered types the dev control the lifetime. But as soon as you start to resolve unregistered types you get the lifetime decided by the container. Imagine if the dev have thought that he have registered it with a specific lifetime. A very hard problem to debug. Checking the container registrations is not the first thing you do. IIRC Unity also builds unregistered concretes that are dependencies to registered types. That's even worse. The registry in the container is there for a reason.

Comment: imho it would be fine to act as a builder if that method is a different one from the others. For instance a `Build` method instead of a `Resolve`. Because in that way it's more obvious that the container can create stuff that is not in it's registry.

Comment: @jgauffin: it's one or the other. Sure, with explicit registrations things are easier do debug. But with implicit registrations, auto wiring is much easier. You just register your implementation against an interface and when you resolve, all additional concrete dependencies are resolved too and assuming you don't care about the lifetime, you get an object with complicated dependency graph resolved.

Comment: Factory methods can exist in containers, but they should be explicit. i.e. the standard Resolve methods should not implement two different behaviors depending on if a component is registered or not. Instead the factory behavior should exist in a  separate method so that the ***dev can control*** when to use it or not. Resolving unregistered dependencies in registered services is just terrible. The lifetime will be the same as the service and not transient as for doing explicit resolves of unregistered types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to make the interface generic:

```
public interface IMessageHandler<T>
{
    void Handle(T message);
}

public class MonkeyHandler : IMessageHandler<Monkey>
{
    public void Handle(Monkey message) {}
}
```

To resolve a handler simply do:

```
var monkeyHandler = yourContainer.Resolve<IMessageHandler<Monkey>>();
```

The problem with that is if you receive messages as `object` you can't do a transition from object to generics at compile time.

```
object message = endPoint.Recieve();

//not fun to do this:
if (message is Monkey)
   container.Resolve<IMessageHandler<Monkey>>((Monkey)message);
```

Instead you need to do a transition from objects to typed handlers.

```
public interface IMessageHandler
{
    void Handle(object message);
}
public interface IMessageHandler<T> : IMessageHandler
{
    void Handle(T message);
}

public class MonkeyHandler : IMessageHandler<Monkey>
{
    public void Handle(Monkey message) {}

    //hide from the public API
    void IMessageHandler.Handle(object message)
    {
        Handle((Monkey)message);
    }
}
```

.. which means that you can now locate it using a `Type`:

```
var genericInterfaceType = typeof(IMessageHandler<>).MakeGenericType(message.GetType());
var handlerObj = container.Resolve(genericInterfaceType);
```

.. so that you can cast it to the base interface and invoke it:

```
var handler = (IMessageHandler)handlerObj;
handler.Handle(message);
```

yay. We got a GOAL!

To remove the repetitive task of transitioning from objects to typed in the handlers you could create a base class:

```
public abstract class HandlerBase<T> : IMessageHandler<T>
{
    public abstract void Handle(Monkey message);

    void IMessageHandler.Handle(object message)
    {
        Handle((T)message);
    }
}

public class MonkeyHandler : HandlerBase<Monkey>
{
    public override void Handle(Monkey message) 
    {
    }
}
```